# Show keybinding with yasnippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I am setting up a new .emacs environment. But with my last setup, the yasnippet menu showed the keybinding. But now it doesn't. It seems very strange. I believe I have the latest version of yasnippet. If I try expanding via a keybinding I already now (like do a "def TAB" in a python buffer) really shows that the keybinding works. But it isn't shown.

This is what I've added to my .emacs file:

```
; Add Yasnippets
(add-to-list 'load-path
          "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas/global-mode 1)
```

And a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What is the value of the variable `yas/use-menu`? (Do `C-h v yas/use-menu` to learn the value.)

Comment: Please open an issue at http://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues

Comment: @JoaoTavora: https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I have this one also in my `.emacs`

`(yas/initialize)`